# generate 16 digit random numbers in oracle

Tags: algorithm, oracle, bigdata

I have to write oracle procedure registering 16 digit security numbers in `registered_security_numbers`.
I know that first 6 digits of security number are either **1234 11** or **1234 12** , rest 10 digits are generated randomly.

I have 2 possible solutions :

1. Write second procedure,which generates all possible security numbers and inserts them in `possible_security_numbers` table, setting property `free=1` .
   Then when i get a request to register a new security number, I query `possible_security_numbers` table for a random security number,which is free and insert it in `registered_security_numbers`.
2. Every time I get a request to register security number, I generate random number from  **1234 1100 0000 0000 - 1234 1299 9999 9999** range until I get security number, which does not exist in  `registered_security_numbers` table and insert it in `registered_security_numbers`.

(1) approach i don't like because `possible_security_numbers` table will contain several billion entries and I am not sure how good it is or how fast select/update can be run.

(2) approach I don't like because if I have many records in `registered_security_numbers` table, generating random number from a range might be repeated many times.

I'd like to know if anyone has other solution or can comment on my solutions, which seem bad to me …

Comment: If the used ids is going to be sparse, I wouldn't pre-generate. Why does it have to be random? Can you pick a random number, and if not available then find the first available id greater than or equal to (or some other algorithm similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many numbers are you actually going to generate?

Imagine that, at most, you're going to generate 1 million (10^6) numbers.  If so, the odds that you're going to need to generate a second random number is roughly 5 in 10^-5 (0.00005 or 0.005%).  If that's the case, it makes little sense to worry about the expense of occasionally generating a second number or the near impossibility of generating a third.  The second approach will be much more efficient.

On the other hand, imagine that you intend to generate 1 billion numbers over time.  If that's the case, then by the end, the odds that you're going to need to generate a second number is 5% and you'll need to generate 3 or 4 numbers reasonably often.  Here, the trade-offs are much harder to figure out.  Depending on the business, the performance impact of catching the unique constraint violation exception and generating multiple numbers on some calls may cause a service to violate the SLA often enough to matter while enumerating the valid numbers may be more efficient on average.

On the third hand, imagine that you intend to generate all 20 billion numbers over time.  If that's the case, by the end, you'd expect to have to generate 10 billion random numbers before you found the one remaining valid number.  If that's the case, the clear advantage will be with the first option of enumerating all possible numbers and tracking which ones have been used.